# Command to run as root on boot isn't working

Tags: boot, ubuntu-12.04, root, xhost

I need to run the following command `sudo xhost SI:localuser:root` every time I start a machine of mine. So I'd like automate this process. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for this.

I tried put this command on my file `/etc/rc.local` but it isn't working, because when I run `xhost` should appear:

```
SI:localuser:<myUser>
SI:localuser:root
```

The file `/etc/rc.local` is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

xhost SI:localuser:root

exit 0
```

Am I missing something?

*PS.: as suggest on the comments**
The thing I'm tying to do is described on this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/573856/cron-jobxhost-is-crashing).
Can I do this on a better way?

Comment: Is that the _entire_ `/etc/rc.local`? You don't have a shebang line?

Comment: I will put the complete fileˆˆ

Comment: I think this might need to be asked on [Ask Ubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com)...

Comment: Why do you need to add `root` to the access list?

Comment: @nerof61 Linux questions are welcome here. Especially if grawity has noticed them :).

Comment: I know, just thinking he would get direct answers from pro's at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, looks like superuser question to me, but I will wait some time after migrate it to AskUbuntu.

Comment: @grawity, I need to run a cron as root and this cron (after other things) should open firefox. The problem is withou this firefox crash when trying to open.

Comment: No, the problem is that you're trying to run Firefox as root...

Comment: Why would a cron job need to open a graphical web browser as the `root` user? This is sounding more and more like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @terdon, I think is a good time to write another question, saying what I'm really trying to doˆˆ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @grawity very correctly points out, this will not work. If you *really* want to do this (which seems like a pretty bad idea), create a `~/.xinitrc` file with these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xhost SI:localuser:root
```

The `xhost` command does not need to be run as `root` since *you* are the owner of the X session. Now, `xinitrc` is pretty old and I am not sure that it will be read by modern Desktop Environments. You could probably achieve the same thing by tweaking your GNOME session properties.

As a general rule enabling root access to your X server is really not a good idea. Any time you *need* root to run a graphical program, you can disable access control:

```
xhost + 
sudo gedit
xhost -
```

I'm pretty sure you don't need to do this on most modern systems though. What exactly are you trying to do? Programs invoked with `sudo` should have access to your X server anyway.

Comment: Most display managers read (source) `~/.xprofile` from their Xsession scripts – I know that GDM, KDM and LightDM do. But I have this feeling that OP is trying to run something *on the login screen*...

Comment: But, IMHO, disabling access control is a much worse idea than giving access to root. Think about it: With `xhost +` you're giving access to root *and* to any other user. (And possibly even to anybody over the network, if Xorg was not launched with `-nolisten tcp`.)

Comment: @grawity yeah, hat's why I added `xhost -` right after it :).

Comment: @terdon, very interesting too. Oh, maybe I can try this. I just using this because when my cron tries to open the firefox it crashes. With `sudo xhost SI:local user:root` I had solve this. I will try to refactory and return.

Comment: @terdon: I noticed, but it's still not any better than `xhost +SI:localuser:root; sudo gedit; xhost -SI:localuser:root`...

Comment: @GarouDan as grawity said, it is not really different from what you are doing. The thing is we suspect that there is a better way of doing what you want to do but you have not explained what it is you are attempting so we cannot give you the right answer. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).

Comment: I tried put `host +` and `host -` on the script runned by my cron, but didn't worked. I will open a question saying what I'm trying to do...

Comment: terdon, please see the question that I did linking to this one I appreciate the help. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work, because:

1. rc.local **runs before** the X11 server is started.
2. rc.local **does not know where** the X11 server is. In other words, it does not know the right value for $DISPLAY.

   Always keep in mind that there can be *multiple* X11 servers – Ubuntu supports "fast user switching", so you might have one Xorg instance for yourself, and a second one for the login screen.
3. rc.local **does not have access** to any of the currently running X11 servers.

   Think about it: If you need to give access to root using `xhost`, it means root doesn't have access yet. And rc.local is running as root.

All three points also apply to cronjobs, to udev rules, and to most other things.

Comment: Interesting. Well I need this because my cron should run as root. So, can I think on a solution to perform this command as root after I have a X?

Comment: gravity, I did another question, explaining what I'm really tying to do. Please take a look to me. I appreciate the help. Thx a lot