# How to run 'ifconfig wlan0 down/up' with a comm user?

Tags: wireless-networking, root, user, ifconfig

I need to run `ifconfig wlan0 down` and `ifconfig wlan0 up` with my common user.

How can I perform this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your script is printing today's date, killing firefox, restarting the network interface and relaunching firefox fullscreen. I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you just want firefox to load every time you log in? WHat's the point of `ifconfig up/down`? If you've just rebooted the interface has just been initialized anyway. I think we are still in [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101) territory :). Why do you want to execute this script?Is it just to get a fullscreen firefox?

Comment: I will take the things clear. But explaining, I need restart firefox periodically. Because the firefox is showing something that need this behaviour.

Comment: OK, so your problem is that you need to be able to run `ifconfig` as a normal user.

Comment: terdon, I agree ˆˆ I think this will solve the problem. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: For future reference, please refrain from dramatically altering your question.  The question that you first posed is significantly different than the one that you have now.  If you need to make changes, try to keep as much of the original information there as possible (unless it's out right incorrect).  If another question arises, then you need to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is give your user the right to run `ifconfig`. The way to do this is to edit the [`etc/sudoers`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821) file:

1. Run `sudo visudo`
2. Add this line to the file (if you are using default settings and you are in `vi`, hit <kbd>i</kbd> to be able to edit the file, <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit editing mode and <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to save and exit):

   ```
   YOUR_USERNAME  ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/ifconfig
   ```

   Obviously, change `YOUR_USERNAME` to your actual username.

That's it, your user can now run `/sbin/ifconfig` without requiring the root password. Your script should now be ready to run.

Comment: terdon, sorry to reopen. But I had miss run. Didn't worked. This line `user YOUR_USERNAME=NOPASSWD:/sbin/ifconfig` is in my sudoers file, but I get bad permissions: `SCIOCSIFFLAGS: Permission denied`. Do you have a ideia to solve this?

Comment: You are using the right user name I assume?

Comment: Yes, for example, `user garou=NOPASSWD:/sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: @GarouDan sorry, my bad, I edited my answer, it should work now. Also, remember to close and save `visudo` the changes won't take effect until you do.

Comment: @GarouDan did you run the command as `sudo /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down` after updating the sudoers file?

Comment: Oh, mazianni. Thx. I was running `ifconfig wlan0 down` and not `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`. It worksˆˆ. Thx a lot terdon, mazianni.